# Why does React Hooks update all child components if any state changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following example:

```
// Form.tsx
import React from "react";

interface FormProps {
  name: string;
  onClick: (n: string) => void;
}

export function Form(props: FormProps) {
  console.log("Form rendered");
  return (
    <input type="button" onClick={() => props.onClick(props.name)} value={`Hello ${props.name}`}/>
  );
}

// App.tsx
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Form } from './Form';

interface AppState {
  val: number;
}

interface AppProps {
}

export function App(props: AppProps) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(1);

  const onClick = useCallback(
    (n: string) => {
      console.log(val);
      setVal(val + 1);
    },
    [val],
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Value: {val}</p>
      <Form name="foo" onClick={onClick}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I pass a prop and a callback to the `Form` component. When the callback is called it updates the `val` state. That state is not used in the `<Form>` element, but React still re-renders it (`Form rendered` gets printed to the console).

This seems unnecessary. The [`useCallback()` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) says:

> useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders

This is quite ambiguous but it seems to suggest that components can be configured to update only if any of their prop values change, and that not using `useCallback()` means that a new function will be created every time `App()` is called, and therefore `Form` will always update.

Since it says "optimized" child components, presumably that isn't the default behaviour? But why? Why would you ever want to update if none of the props change? Isn't the entire point of "optimizing" a component via `shouldComponentUpdate` that you can be more relaxed than "did the prop change?"

Comment: But props and state are not the same. Your Form might have state changed internally after interacting with it. Therefore when rerendering the parent (App in your case) you have to make a choice what happens with a child. In most cases I find default rerendering fits most of the time well. The opposite of this is to never rerender children if their props do not change, but your component might depend on other data like URL params or context so not rerendering it might leave the whole thing stale. Also the statement `This seems unnecessary.` might require some data to back it up.

Comment: Nah it's not that. It's that the prop actually *was* changing because in the `onClick` callback I updated `val`, and that callback itself depends on `val`, so it gets recreated, and then that means that the `onClick` prop has changed so you do need to update the `Form`. If you change `[val]` to `[]` then it doesn't re-render the form, as expected. (And it warns you about the fact that the `onClick` callback only captures the initial value of `val`, so it doesn't really work properly, but the point is that you call `setVal()` and it doesn't need to re-render `<Form>` because no props change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the state (`val`) as a dependency to `useCallback()`, a new function is generated when `val` changes. This causes the child component to rerender.

To skip the need to include `val` as a dependency while still having the value of the previous state when you want to update it, use an [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
>   function to setState. The function will receive the previous value,
>   and return an updated value.

Example:

```
const onClick = useCallback(
  (n: string) => {
    setVal(v => v + 1);
  },
  [],
);
```